# Why can't HTTP process write into directory with group permissions?

Tags: macos, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I'm running into an issue on both, an Amazon instance and my Mac.

I have the two users

- `ec2-user:ec2-user` (`myuser:staff` for the mac)
- `apache:ec2-user`  (`_www:staff` for the mac)

.
If I have a directory created by `apache`, the `ec2-user` can write perfectly underneath it

```
drwxrwsr-x 3 apache ec2-user 4.0K Mar 27 20:37 /path/to/sample/dir
// ec2-user can write here
```

But on the reverse scenario, if `ec2-user` is the owner of the directory, when apache tries to write underneath it, it throws an error saying it doesn't have enough permissions.

```
drwxrwsr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K Mar 27 20:37 /path/to/sample/dir
// apache CANNOT write here
```

But if I change the permissions to 777, then `apache is able to write inside it

```
drwxrwsrwx 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4.0K Mar 27 20:37 /path/to/sample/dir
// apache CAN write here
// file created would have `664 apache:ec2-user` permissions
```

#### So the question is

Why though the two users have the same group, is `apache` not able to write into a directory that clearly has write permissions to the group?

---

*Additional*:
Though `apache` writes with `ec2-user` as group, when I execute the following, I realized that apache does not belong to the `ec2-user` group, so how come when it writes, files and directories created by it have such group?

```
sudo -u apache id
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and talking with some SysAdmins, the answer was straight into the groups that `apache` belongs to.

Regardless of the factor that the directories files by `apache` had the `ec2-user` group, didn't mean that `apache` belonged to that group.

So, to address this specific request, all I had to do, is add Apache to the `ec2-user` group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G ec2-user apache
```

I haven't very well figured out the mac version, but it goes along the ways of using the `dseditgroup` command.